# How to add valueChange action programatically for WKInterfaceSwitch in WatchApp

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit

I am working on Watch App and In one of the watch screen, I have TableView(`WKInterfaceTable`) with switch each cell.

I want to add action on the switch to notify switch value changed and this action I want to add in my Interface file, not in custom row file.

Can anyone have an idea of how to add action programmatically on Switch (`WKInterfaceSwitch`)?

**See attached screen for Ref:**

[image]

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Try using `addTarget` method for the switch. `switch.addTarget`

Comment: I am using WatchKit and there is no method like addTarget in watchKit have you use watchKit ?

Comment: refer [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29735301/wkinterfaceswitch-or-wkinterfacebutton-in-a-table-row-which-row-was-touched) if it helps!